# Replace duplicate values in a list with incrementing number

Tags: list-manipulation

For an input list of numbers ie:

{6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6}

For the first value in the list I'd like to replace it with 1, and also all duplicates of the first value with 1.  Then the next value 4 would be replaced by 2, along with all duplicates in the same way etc.  Each new value in the list would increment the replacement value so the list would become:

{1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1}

Another example:

{7, -1, -9, 7, -9, -1, 7} would become: {1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1}

cheers,
Jamie